# React Js Babel Unable to compile css file and doesnt recognise .classname

Tags: css, reactjs, babeljs

Please help. Thanks in Advance

In .css file it shows

```
SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token (2:0)
1 | // Add your site styles here. Feel free to import!
2 | .titleBar {
  | ^
```

and package.json is

```
 {   "name": "pharmacy2u-technical-test",   "version": "1.0.0",  
 "description": "A TV schedule viewer",   "main": "./server.js",  
 "scripts": {
     "run": "node ."   },   "dependencies": {
     "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
     "core-js": "^3.20.2",
     "css-modulesify": "^0.28.0",
     "express": "^4.17.2",
     "react": "^17.0.2",
     "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
     "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"   },
     "devDependencies": {
     "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
     "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.18.6",
     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.8",
     "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
     "babel-plugin-css-modules-transform": "^1.6.2",
     "browserify": "^17.0.0",
     "sass": "^1.47.0",
     "through2": "^4.0.2"   } }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting code, but you may want to read the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and also look at the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: Thanks but it was urgent

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please see this post to edit your question so the community can answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask